# What is the inverse Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc} \Big{(} \prod_{k=1}^{m} \big{(} k(z-m+1) -z) \big{)} \Big{)} $?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, interpolation, trigonometric-polynomials

For a certain interpolation problem, I'm looking into a sequence of functions of the form $$f_{m}(z) = \operatorname{sinc} \Bigg{(} \prod_{k=1}^{m} \big{(} k(z-m+1) -z) \big{)} \Bigg{)} . $$
Here, $m>1$ is an integer and $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ is the normalized sinc function.

I'd like to compute the inverse Fourier transform of $f_{m}(\cdot) $ for every positive integer $m$. However, I'm not sure how to do so, and whether it's possible at all.

I do know the following inverse Fourier transforms:

1. The normalized sinc function becomes a box pulse function: $\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{x} {[} \operatorname{sinc} (\pi x) {]} (t) = \frac{\operatorname{sgn} (\pi - t) + \operatorname{sgn}(t+\pi) }{2\sqrt{2}\pi}  .$
2. The unnormalized sinc of a parabola becomes something more [involved](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+fourier+sinc%28x%5E%282%29%29): \begin{align}\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{x} {[} \operatorname{sinc} (x^{2}) {]} (t) =  & \hspace{1mm} \frac{i}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} |t| \operatorname{erf} \Bigg{(} \frac{\big{(} \frac{1+i}{2} \big{)} |t| }{\sqrt{2}} \Bigg{)} -  \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} |t| \operatorname{erfi} \Bigg{(} \frac{\big{(} \frac{1+i}{2} \big{)} |t| }{\sqrt{2}} \Bigg{)} \hspace{1mm} + \\ & \hspace{1mm} \sin\bigg{(}\frac{t^{2}}{4} \bigg{)} + \cos\bigg{(}\frac{t^{2}}{4} \bigg{)}.\end{align}

(Above, $\operatorname{erf}(\cdot)$ and $\operatorname{erfi}(\cdot)$ denote the error function and complex error function, respectively.)

However, I haven't been able to find any inverse Fourier transforms of (un)normalized sinc functions of polynomials of degree higher than two. I did find quite a bit on the inverse Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}(x)^{N}$, but that's not what I'm looking for at the moment.

> **Question**: what is $\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{x} {[} f_{m}(x) {]} (t) $? I'm specifically interested in the inverse Fourier transform of the normalized sinc of this particular sequence of polynomials, but more generally I'm also curious about the inverse transforms of the sinc of other higher-degree polynomials.

Comment: the (inverse) Fourier transform of $\text{sinc}\, z^2$ is a Fresnel integral, higher powers of $z$ do not seem to have an answer in terms of a known special function.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Hmm alright, thank you